# Comparing hours and day with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, time

There are similar topics on website about comparing time but I have a little bit different problem. I need to compare a specified time and now.

I have some particular times (days, opening and closing hours  for a shop) For example: Monday opening 10:00 am - closing 6:30 pm

I want to create an application which checks time and informs to user: shop is open or close, like google app.

I need to find subtraction's result of now and specified time: for example if day is monday(closing time is 6:30) and time is 5:20 pm, result will be 1:10 and it means shop is open, but I don't know how I can convert 6:30 into hours format.

Comment: use Date() ..im sure this is a duplicate, try google

Comment: @Pootie Great Idea! Why didn't I think to try google !!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to render contextual difference between two timestamps in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168924/how-to-render-contextual-difference-between-two-timestamps-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

Based on the information you provided, you can just do the following:

```
var time = "6:30",
    splitTime = time.split(':'),
    hours = splitTime[0],
    minutes = splitTime[1];
```

Then you'll have variables for hours and minutes that you can effectively use for comparison.

Comment: Good method, but for example, if time is 10:50 am, result will be 10-6=4 and 50-30=20 it opens 4 hours 20 min and it wont be correct.

Comment: Right.   You can't compare AM to PM that way.  Provided time.endsWith('pm'), you can just add 12 to the hours.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, set the default timezone:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');
```

And then, you can calcul the difference between now and the closed time:

```
$diff = strtotime('today 18:30') - strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i'));
if ($diff > 0) 
    echo 'The shop is opening. Closed in ' . gmdate("H:i", $diff);
else
    echo 'The shop is closed. Please come back tomorrow.';
```

Comment: thanks for answer, javascript or jquery would be nice but I am gonna try.

Comment: Up to you. With js, you can use Date. E.g. var closedTime = new Date("June 11, 2016 18:30:00");

Answer (score 1):

From what i understood you can make that by

- Storeing closing hours/minutes in array and store each one in a variable
- Get current hours/minutes and store each one in a variable
- Get remaining hours/minutes
- Make if conditionals to fix the result in case of

  - Remaining hours greater than or equal to 1 and remaining minutes less than 0 (minus)
  - if hours current time greater than closing time

http://codepen.io/El-Oz/pen/beEOMv

```js
window.onload = function () {

  'use strict'; 


  var closingTime, 
      closingHour,
      closingMin,

      currDate,
      currTime,
      currHour,
      currMin,

      remHours,
      remMin,

      remMessage;


  closingTime = ['18', '30'];

  /* Get Closing hours/minutes */
  closingHour = closingTime[0];
  closingMin = closingTime[1];


  currDate = new Date().toString().split(" ");
  currTime = currDate[4].split(':');

  /* Get Current hours/minutes */
  currHour = currTime[0];
  currMin = currTime[1];


  if (currHour >= 10) {

    /* Get remaining hours/minutes */
    remHours = closingHour - currHour;
    remMin = closingMin - currMin;

    if ( remHours >= 1 && remMin < 0) {
      remHours -= 1;
      remMin = 60 + remMin;
    }

    remMessage =  "Remaining Hours: " + remHours + "<br>" + " Remaining Minutes: " + remMin;

    if ( (remHours === 0 && remMin === 0 ) || (remHours === 0 && remMin < 0 ) || remHours < 0 ) {
      remMessage = " Sorry, The shop is closed!";
    }

  // if current hour less than 10
  } else {
    var remToOpen = 10 - currHour;
    remMessage = "The shop will be opened after " + remToOpen + ' hours';
  }

  document.querySelector('p').textContent = remMessage;

};
```

```html
<p></p>
```